# Control ascx does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Web Application project which has the below structure

```
ProjectName
-Controls
--WebControls
--MyControl.ascx

-CustomerControls
--CustDetails.ascx
```

In the CustDetails.ascx control i am trying to load MyControl.ascx, so i have added a reference on the page (not codebehind) i.e.

```
<%@ Register Src="../Controls/WebControls/MyControl.ascx" TagPrefix="Ctrl" TagName="CustCtrol" %>
```

The page loads without errors.

I now add the below code to codebehind

```
LoadControl = Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
```

but i receive ***"The file '/MyControl.ascx' does not exist."***

I try changing the path to

```
~/Controls/WebControls/MyControl.ascx
```

but same error. Changed it to

```
../Controls/WebControls/MyControl.ascx
```

then get "*Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.*"

I've tried variations and searched google but i cant understand where ive gone wrong?

Edit 1

Image attached of directory[image: Directory Image]

Comment: Web Site or Web Forms template?

Comment: Its a Web Application (when i build it creates a dll in the bin directory)

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11600980/7565464 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/709862/7565464

Comment: @Efe, the URLs shows to loading from root. I believe the question is; how to load from a deep directory /Controls/WebControls/abc.ascx?

Comment: @Anil Thanks for your point, It was a miss undestanding

Comment: You are embedding MyControl in CustDetails control. What page are you trying to embed the CustDetails on and why are you trying to load it dynamically - is this a requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the directory structure here:

> ProjectName
>
> -Controls
>
> --WebControls
>
> --MyControl.ascx

It says that MyControl.ascx is inside Controls directory, not WebControls.

You have 2 options:

1) move MyControl.ascx to WebControls directory, rebuild solution and these codes will work:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/WebControls/MyControl.ascx" TagPrefix="ctrl" TagName="CustControl" %>
```

and

```
LoadControl = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/WebControls/MyControl.ascx");
```

2) keep it in the same directory as you listed( MyControl.ascx in Controls directory) and change path in above codes to these:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/MyControl.ascx" TagPrefix="ctrl" TagName="CustControl" %>
```

and

```
LoadControl = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/MyControl.ascx");
```

No need to use Server.MapPath.

Also, if you have public methods or properties defined in MyControl code behind class, you need to cast the loaded control to MyControl in order to access those methods and properties just like I did here:

```
LoadControl = Page.LoadControl("...") as MyControl;
//or
LoadControl = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("...");
```

Comment: I think path is Controls/WebControls/MyControl.ascx

Comment: @Anil yes I think so, I just tested it right now and "~/path/to/MyControl.ascx" worked like a charm.

Comment: @Computer, can you please add the error you are getting when you are trying "I try changing the path to

~/Controls/WebControls/MyControl.ascx
but same error", as per Efe this should work.

Comment: Thanks guys i will look at the recommendation given above. I have attached an image of the directory structure to avoid any confusion

Comment: @Computer Then option 1 will definitely do the job. Do not use '..' when registering the controller. If you wanna be sure, just drag MyControl.ascx from solution explorer and drop it into CustControl.ascx page and you will see '~' insted of '..'.